# How do i place 2 CSS rectangles side by side? By default, they appear one below the other

Tags: python, html, css

Here is the code:

```
<head>
      <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="01">
    <title>
        Slot Data
    </title>
</head>          
<body> 
    <style>
    div
    {
        height: 100px;
        width: 50px;
        background-color: green;
    }
   </style>
<div></div>
   <style>
   div
    {
        height: 100px;
        width: 50px;
        background-color: green;
    }
   </style>
<div></div>

</body>
```

They appear exactly one below the other.

Also, I need a way to change the color "green" to "red" for a condition written in python. For which, the snippet is:

```
if count1 >= 0.65 * 122*85:
                print "car0 absent"
                cv2.rectangle(dst1,(8,8),(340,488),(0,255,0),2) #green
                cv2.putText(dst1,'slot empty',(12,450), font, 1,(255,255,255),1,cv2.LINE_AA)
                f = open('test.html','r')
                filedata = f.read()
                f.close()
                newdata = filedata.replace("red","green")
                f = open('test.html','w')
                f.write(newdata)
                f.close()


            else:
                print "car0 present"
                cv2.rectangle(dst1,(8,8),(340,488),(0,0,255),2) #red
                cv2.putText(dst1,'slot occupied',(12,450), font, 1,(255,255,255),1,cv2.LINE_AA)
                f = open('test.html','r')
                filedata = f.read()
                f.close()
                newdata = filedata.replace("green","red")
                f = open('test.html','w')
                f.write(newdata)
                f.close()
```

and I have the same code for another car1.
How do i address the two rectangles differently? the replacing mechanism will replace the colors of both the CSS rectangles, which I do not want.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use `float:left` to make them appear side-by-side

Answer (score 2):

[`<div>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div) are normally displayed as [block level elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) but can be made to display next to each other with [`display: inline-block`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).

You seem pretty new to CSS/HTML and might do well to do some research or tutorials to get a firmer grasp on things-- CSS can be strange at first, but gets much easier as you get more familiar with it.

Personally, I would use classes to target the elements appropriately.  As for getting elements by class in Python, I'm not really sure-- I can't say I know off the top of my head how you are manipulating these things with Python at all-- is this displaying/executing in a browser?

I created a snippet below w/ an example.

```css
.rect {
    height: 100px;
    width: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: green;
}
.alert {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<head>
      <!--<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="01">-->
    <title>
        Slot Data
    </title>
</head>          
<body> 
  <div class="rect"></div>

  <div class="rect alert"></div>

</body>
```

Please note, there are other ways to do this-- CSS provides all sorts of positioning/layout tools.  Good luck!

Comment: Hey! thanks a lot! I'm actually newer than "new" haha!

Answer (score 1):

You can use **float:left** to make them display next to eachother.

```
float:left
```

**Just remember to clear it**, if you want a second row.  Just create a small element with the styling

```
clear:both;
```

Here's a handy fiddle that will **really help** in understanding how this **css** works:

https://jsfiddle.net/nfnneil/6jgsp9dx/